# VBO's in openGL

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, vbo

I am currently learning to use openGL and LWJGL. When trying to set up some Vertex Buffer Objects i get the error message:

```
Invalid memory access of location 0x0 rip=0x10f95f42f
```

Here is my code.

```
public class Test {

public Test(){
    try {
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(768, 512));
        Display.setTitle("This is a title!");
        Display.create();
    } catch (LWJGLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Initialize openGL
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    final int vertexAmount = 3;
    final int vertexSize = 2;
    final int colorSize = 3;

    FloatBuffer vertexData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(vertexAmount * vertexSize);
    vertexData.put(new float[]{-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f});
    vertexData.flip();

    FloatBuffer colorData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(vertexAmount * colorSize);
    colorData.put(new float[]{1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1});
    colorData.flip();

    int vboVertexHandle = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboVertexHandle);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    int vboColorHandle = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboColorHandle);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    while(!Display.isCloseRequested()){
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboVertexHandle);
        glVertexPointer(vertexSize, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboColorHandle);
        glVertexPointer(colorSize, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);

        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

        Display.update();
        Display.sync(60);
    }

    glDeleteBuffers(vboVertexHandle);
    glDeleteBuffers(vboColorHandle);

    Display.destroy();

}

public static void main(String[] args){

    Test test = new Test();

}

}
```

Comment: I'd try moving the `glEnableClientState` calls up before you bind, and change the second `glVertexPointer` to `glColorPointer`.

Comment: @Robert Why not post that as an answer?

Comment: @AndreasHaferburg Because those are two bugs I found glancing through the code that may or may not be related to the issue he is having. I was also about to leave when I saw the question, so I wrote down a very short answer without an explanation of *why* that might be his issue. I think I'll write up a full answer now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue may be that you are enabling `GL_COLOR_ARRAY` without ever giving it any data. I noticed that in your while loop, you have this block of code:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboVertexHandle);
glVertexPointer(vertexSize, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboColorHandle);
glVertexPointer(colorSize, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);
```

Notice how the last line is also `glVertexPointer`? This should be `glColorPointer`, to specify that the data in the bound buffer is for `GL_COLOR_ARRAY`, not `GL_VERTEX_ARRAY`.

I don't think this really makes a difference, but I always like to enable/disable things before I set their data, so if the above doesn't work, try moving the two `glEnableClientState` calls to before the first `glBindBuffer` call in the while loop and see if that changes anything.

Comment: It was the GL_VERTEX_ARRAY that was supposed to be GL_COLOR_ARRAY that was the bug here it seems.